# How to convert Apache .htaccess files into Lighttpd rules?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, lighttpd

It's big problem to convert mod_rewrite rules to lighttpd format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is generally a case of just going through one by one and converting them.  I don't know of any automated means,

The docs - http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs:ModRewrite - has the regexes available, and some examples.

if there are any particularly problematical items, I'd edit the question to show them, and ask for the answers here.

Comment: Indeed there is no automated way to do it. The syntaxes and possibilities of both are too different to allow for an automatic conversion anyway.

Answer (score 0):

url rewriting does not work within a $HTTP["url"] conditional. [http://forum.lighttpd.net/topic/1092#3028]